# Regex catch unwanted left side char

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The following regex catch all HTML style tags:

```
[^noscript\>]<style[^>]*>([^<]+)?<[\s\/]+style>
```

The first part **[^noscript>]** is used to ignore any style tag wrapped by a noscript tag.

The problem is, the pattern appear to return an unwanted left side char, how to avoid that? See this example https://regex101.com/r/aA6ihs/1/

Comment: I will just mention https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have no other option here !

Comment: If you can apply a regular expression to some HTML text, you can also parse it properly. So, yes, you do have options.

Comment: @Peter i had tried DOMDocument()  it doens't work correctly. It simply modify the parsed html which definitely, is not something to consider here.

Comment: I know this means extra work, but may I suggest adding another question which is how you tried to solve it in DOMDocument and what failed and perhaps we can help you sort the problem out that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this would be better to do with an HTML parser, you can skip over all the `<noscript>` tags with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - try to match `<noscript>...</noscript>`, and if it gets matched, fail the pattern at the end, and continue searching for matches *after* the end:

```
<noscript>.*?<\/noscript>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<style[^>]*>([^<]+)?<[\s\/]+style>
```

https://regex101.com/r/aA6ihs/3

Answer (score 0):

Here, we would simply capture `noscript` tags, add an `if` statement to ignore those, then we would be retuning our desired output with a simple expression such as:

```
(<noscript>)[\s\S]+?<\/noscript>|<style(.+?)>(.+?)<\/style>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wr4Lcr/2/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(<noscript>)[\s\S]+?<\/noscript>|<style(.+?)>(.+?)<\/style>/mi';
$str = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
        <style type="text/css"></style>
<noscript><style>

< / style></noscript>
                    <!-- Twitter Cards Meta by USM  STARTS-->
                <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />


        <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>

<link rel="pingback" href="/xmlrpc.php">
<noscript><style>

< / style></noscript>
        ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[1] != '<noscript>') {
        echo $value[3];
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}
```